# How can I add a new attribute to an existing xml node using wpf and c#?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

I'm trying to add a new attribute to an existing xml node, my xml looks like this:

```
<Atletas>
<Atleta Id="0" Nombre="TextBox4" Genero="Masculino" Edad="TextBox"  />
<Atleta Id="1" Nombre="TextBox345" Genero="Masculino" Edad="TextBox" />
<Atleta Id="2" Nombre="Daniel1" Genero="Masculino" Edad="TextBox"  />
<Atleta Id="3" Nombre="TextBox4" Genero="Masculino" Edad="TextBox" />
<Atleta Id="4" Nombre="Daniel2" Genero="Masculino" Edad="23" />
<Atleta Id="5" Nombre="Juan" Genero="Masculino" Edad="25" />
</Atletas>
```

I want my xml looks like this:

```
<Atletas>
<Atleta Id="0" Nombre="Daniel" Genero="Masculino" Edad="25" Peso="89" />
<Atleta Id="1" Nombre="John" Genero="Masculino" Edad="22"  />
<Atleta Id="2" Nombre="Tom" Genero="Masculino" Edad="21" Peso="78"/>
<Atleta Id="3" Nombre="Kerry" Genero="Masculino" Edad="18" />
<Atleta Id="4" Nombre="Peter" Genero="Masculino" Edad="23" Peso="76" />
<Atleta Id="5" Nombre="Juan" Genero="Masculino" Edad="25" />
</Atletas>
```

Using linq, how can i write a query in order to add a new attribute to a selected node using its Id as an identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [XElement.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to add content (like attributes) to elements:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);

var atleta = xdoc.Root.Elements("Atleta")
                 .FirstOrDefault(a => (int)a.Attribute("Id") == 3);

atleta.SetAttributeValue("Edad", 21);
atleta.Add(new XAttribute("Peso", 78));
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

After executing this code `Atleta` element with attribute `Id` equal to `3` will look like:

```
<Atleta Id="3" Nombre="TextBox4" Genero="Masculino" Edad="21" Peso="78"/>
```

Suggested reading: [Programming Guide (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx). If you have any questions to code above or other tasks you need to complete, then just read this guide.